# How to check if a None exists in a List of Future[Option]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, future

Say we have:

```
val listOfYetToBeMaybePeople = List[Future[Option[Person]]]
```

Is there a non-blocking way to get a `Future[Boolean]` of `true` iff all elements have `Some(Person)` or `false` if at least one is `None`?

Comment: Do you mean a `Future[Boolean]`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, sorry.  I will update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
val listOfYetToBeMaybePeople: List[Future[Option[Person]]] = 
val allExist: Future[Boolean] = 
  Future.sequence(listOfYetToBeMaybePeople).map(_.forall(_.nonEmpty))
```

Explanation:

- `sequence` transforms `List` of `Future`s into future of list
- `forall` checks a predicate on all elements of the list
- `nonEmpty` checks whether an `Option` is actually a `Some`.

Returns future with `true` if all people turn out to exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
Future.sequence(listOfYetToBeMaybePeople).map(!_.exists(_.isEmpty))
```

Comment: You are probably missing a `!` right after `map`? This here gives `true` if there will exist a `None`. It was supposed to give a `true` if all will be `Some`.

Comment: It's interesting, because you answered the question in the title (which was complementary to the question in the question-body). I always have the complementary problem of answering the question in the question-body, mostly ignoring the question-title. It's kind-of 50%-50% what the OP turns out to mean (title vs. body), so the missing `!` was not your fault ;)